# How to add Background processing permission to BB10 App ported from android?

Tags: android, background, blackberry-10

I am porting existing android app to BB10 but it seems its not working when app is in background. It requires a special permission to do so which is `run_when_backgrounded` but i cant find the way to add it.

i tried to change bar file manually but when trying to install getting following error `result::failure 880 META-INF/RDK.SF: SHA-512-Digest-Manifest mismatch`.

UPDATE:Added this using custom manifest but it seems its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headless (background) applications are not yet supported in Blackberry 10. That functionality is going to be added soon in next SDK releases (likely 10.2).

At the moment BlackBerry 10 does not support "headless" processes for third-party applications as it stated [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/getting_started/porting/multitasking.html).

Comment: thanks bro i had seen this before, anyway i think there is no way out . what to do...